# Running tasks from broadcast receiver while app is closed [Android]

Tags: android, sqlite, broadcastreceiver

I have an app that downloads data and put it into an SQLite Database when a notification is issued. This works fine while the app is in use but I need it to work when the app is closed too.

I have set up a `BroadcastReceiver` within that is called when the app is closed but I'm not sure how to get it to continue with adding to the database.

Here is the code I am using:

**AndroidManifest.xml**

```
<manifest....

   <application...

     <receiver android:name=".broadcast.PacksReceiver" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="ADD_PACK" >
            </action>
        </intent-filter>
    </receiver>
```

**PacksReceiver**

```
public class PacksReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {
  @Override
  public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
    Log.d("PacksReceiver", "onReceive");

    String message = intent.getStringExtra("message");

    PacksActivity pa = new PacksActivity();
    pa.downloadPack(null, message);
  }
}
```

**PacksActivity**

```
public void downloadPack(View v, String thisPackID){
    Log.d("download", "pack");
    //THIS LOG IS CALLED EVERYTIME
    vRef = v;
    if(vRef != null){
        runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                onScreenProgressBar = (ProgressBar) vRef.findViewById(R.id.onScreenProgress);
                onScreenProgressCircle = (ProgressBar) vRef.findViewById(R.id.onScreenProgressCircle);
                dlPercent = (TextView) vRef.findViewById(R.id.dlPercent);

                onScreenProgressCircle.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);

                onScreenProgressBar.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                onScreenProgressCircle.setProgress(0);
            }
        });
    }
    if(thisPackID == null){
        thisPackID = pack_id;
    }

    String url = MyApp.getAppContext().getString(R.string.serverURL) +
            MyApp.getAppContext().getString(R.string.getAppendixA) + "/" + thisPackID;
    Intent appA_Intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SYNC, null, this, DownloadService.class);
    appA_Intent.putExtra("url", url);
    appA_Intent.putExtra("onCreate", "false");
    appA_Intent.putExtra("receiver", downloadPackReceiver);
    appA_Intent.putExtra("downloadType", "GET_APPENDIX_A");
    appA_Intent.putExtra("requestId", 101);
    MyApp.getAppContext().startService(appA_Intent);
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

start the Service from

```
onReceive()
```

method because you can get mutiple broadcast one after another.

Answer (score 0):

Write the code  to add data in your database in your PackReciever inside OnRecieve() Method because that is where you recieve push notifications.

Answer (score 0):

Don't call activity inside the receiver. Instead, use IntentService to download all packs. IntentService automatically finishes once it completes its work.

Override its onHandleIntent() method and download packs and save to database there.